# Why didn't C++11 incorporate all of Boost's type traits?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

As you know, Boost has a lot of type traits. C++11 brought some of them over to the standard, e.g. the `is_pointer` and `is_base_of`.

There are others like `has_greater` and `has_greater_equal` that C++11 did not incorporate. Why not? Are there any plans to include them in the next standards? Were there some papers by the standards-committe or Bjarne Stroustrup on this?

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll find a definite answer but just speculation for now. A guess could be that they did not believe there was enough request or use and hence would rather keep the new standard concise as possible for now.

Comment: @j_kubik: It's not a dup. The pointed answer if for 03 to 11. This question is more on the 11 to 14.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia I admit that you have some right, but my point is that perhaps the question is slightly different, but the answer remains the same. Future standards will have to contain almost everything from the current one, so not adding stuff now gives more freedom in the future - if existing implementations will evolve and be widely used, they will get to the standard eventually.

Comment: @j_kubik The answer is completely different – the other question is unspecific and doesn’t mention traits at all. The way I understand OP, he’s asking for specific potential shortcomings that would have led to the exclusion of these traits in the standard. Nothing in the other question addresses this.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia I understand that this is more specific question, but unless there is rejected proposition somewhere in the history of discussions on new standard, we will probably never know if those type traits were somehow exceptionally ugly not to get to the standard.

Comment: reopening, as the close-reason is entirely unsatisfactory. This is not an "opinion-based" question. The question is not "what do you wish the reason was?" but "what was the reason". Obviously, there can only be one answer to that question. EDIT: I edited the question to state that, and not "do you know...?".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++11 was approved in August 2011.  Operator detection was added to Boost Type Traits for 1.48.0, which came out in November 2011.

I do not believe anyone proposed them for C++14, and that is now frozen.  IMNSHO it would be nice if someone proposes it for C++17.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is in topic for S.O. (may be more in programmers?)
Anyway, Boost and ISO are two very different things. The "standard" is what the language "IS", and contains what is required to characterize the language for ANY purpose.
Boost is a library that "extends" functionality to specific problems.

Boost committee operate on "quality" of the code (not on its subject), the standard operates on the "spread" (assuming the quality is given). Not everything that is "good" is also "common". What boost does goes in the standard when it is found to be enough common. And does not go "the way boost did it". It goes in form of a specification that compiler distributor have to satisfy.

Boost is written in a way that many compiler can work with it.
The standard library is written in a way the compiler it goes with (or the family of compilers it goes with) plays better with it (and there are virtually a number as the compiler family can be out there). The kind of optimization and eventual low level tweaking is different.

The fact that some boost libraries became part of the standard is not an automatic consequence. It's just a matter of coincidence of some "good ideas" that where found needed in virtually any code.

That said, your intent is not necessarily wrong: it may happen for the particular subject you asked. But there is no "migration progress" from boost to the standard and no standard prerequisite that requires to be before in boost.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the OP is looking for whether there are maybe specific shortcomings in the traits the standards committee decided not to carry over.

Comment: Yes, this is also possible. It depends on what you and the OP mean with "*short* term". Is C++11 to c++14 transition *short* to both of you? If no, my generic answer make sense. If yes, better answer to that specific subject may come. Good point!

Comment: Boost and ISO are not _that_ different. There is a very significant personal overlap. See first line of http://www.boost.org/community/

Comment: @MSalters: the fact that some electricians are also plumbers doesn't make electrotechnics and hydraulics the same thing, IMHO.